# D3: converting from string to number with unary + sign is not working

Tags: d3.js, count, type-conversion, nest, rollup

I have a CSV file that I have imported.
after import, I have used nest and rollup to organize the data like below.

```
      var data_group = d3.nest()
                      .key(function(d) {return +d.year;})
                      .key(function(d) {return +d.average_rating;})
                      .rollup(function (count) {
                        return count.length;
                      })
                      .entries(data);

      console.log(data_group)
```

However, when I look at the console.log, the year and the the average_rating are strings.
I would like them to be a number.
How can I achieve this? Below is a picture of the output.
Also, can someone explain why they are not numbers after the + sign?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly as expected, as described in the [d3.nest documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nests). It also states explicitly in the documentation of [nest.key](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#nest_key) that "The key function ... must return a string identifier".

The first few lines of the example given there look like so:

```
[{key: "1931", values: [
   {key: "Manchuria", values: [
   {yield: 27.00, variety: "Manchuria", year: 1931, site: "University Farm"},
   {yield: 48.87, variety: "Manchuria", year: 1931, site: "Waseca"},
...
```

In particular, note that the first line starts `key: "1931"`, even though `1931` is an integer value in the input data. That 1931 appears as an integer in the result only when it's a value, as in the lat two lines.

It's probably also worth pointing out that `d3.nest` is long since deprecated and was even removed in V6 several years ago. You should seriously consider using `d3.group` and/or `d3.rollup` in V7.